# Resolve woocommerce hook woocommerce_email_footer function causing recursion

Tags: recursion, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce hook `woocommerce_email_footer()` and inside my function, I need to call `$email->get_content()` which causes recursion and PHP memory error and WordPress exits with system error

Tried to remove the hook before calling the `$email->get_content()` and adding the hook back right after this call. However, this may not be a foolproof solution since some other session which hits exactly at the time when my function has removed the action might totally miss the hook custom action

I've written the following code in functions.php of my theme to capture the mail contents (mail body) into a local file just before it is being sent whenever a new order is received

```
    //
    // Capture the contents of the Emails sent and save into local files 
    // These Local files are used for further messaging through different channels
    // 

    function Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File ( $email ) { 
       if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {

    // Remove the action temporarily so as not to cause Recursion while we refer to $email functions
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File', 20, 1 ); 

        $TargetFilename = '/home/users/....../Sent_Mail.html' ;

          $html_message = $email->get_content();
          $formatted_message = $email->style_inline($html_message);
          file_put_contents($TargetFilename, $formatted_message);
     }

    // Put the action back to original state
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File', 20, 1 ); 
    }; 

    // add the action 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File', 20, 1 );
```

Please note in the above function, I'm referring the $email->get_content() public function.

If I do not do the `remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File', 20, 1 );` this function becomes recursive and fails with a PHP memory error.

Although this is a workable solution, Removing the action can potentially cause another instance of the `customer_processing_order` from another user to miss the action and not come to this function if that session hits exactly at the time when this current session has removed the action and before adding the action again.

I'm sure I'm not doing it right! Is there any better way to accomplish what I need - basically I need the exact formatted mail content to be stored in a local file whenever the order is received. Similarly, I will need local file stored for Order completion and order hold, etc. but at later point of time.

Want to achieve storing formatted email into a local file a) without causing recursion / PHP memory errors b) without having to miss some instances of the execution missing the custom code attached to the hook.

Comment: fairly sure that the recursion would be caused by placing the remove_action line within the function it's calling. This would need to be placed outside the function.

Comment: Hi @Matts Thanks for your comment - Just want to reiterate that by putting the remove_action I'm able to successfully avoid recursion. If I do not have remove_action, what is happening is when I make a call to $edit->get_content() which is trying to get me the mail body including 'footers' once again encounters the hook and comes inside my function again.. repeats. So temporarily putting remove_action inside my function is actually solving the recursion problem, but having this remove_action may cause functional issue as my function may get skipped in some cases..

Comment: In the above update I mean to say $email->get_content() - not $edit->get _content()   -- its a typo..

Comment: The procedure I would follow is to use add_action once (outside the function), and not use remove_action unless removing a built in function rather than your own.

Comment: Yes that's what I want too. But if I don't remove it is causing recursion and PHP memory error.

Comment: function Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File ( $email ) { 
   if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {


      $html_message = $email->get_content();
      $formatted_message = $email->style_inline($html_message);
      file_put_contents($TargetFilename, $formatted_message);
 }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'Save_Email_Contents_into_Local_File', 20, 1 );

Comment: This above code causes recursion and PHP memory error.

Comment: You could edit your question with a stack trace of the error. Usually the error message will show you where the error is from.

Comment: Thank you for the response - The remove_action helped solve the problem and now there is no recursion. Thank you.